# Ошибка компиляции при установке Glide

Tags: android, glide

После установки библиотеки Glide выходит ошибка:

> Error:Conflict with dependency
>   'com.android.support:support-annotations' in project ':app'. Resolved
>   versions for app (26.1.0) and test app (26.0.2) differ. See
>   http://g.co/androidstudio/app-test-app-conflict for details.

Подскажите, как ее можно исправить?

Answer (score 0):

Ну, конфликт версий же. Ясно дело, в зависимостях эти самые аннотации должны быть версии 26.0.2.

Comment: Честно говоря, не ясно, как это исправить. Студия не предлагает никаких обновлений, простая замена номера версии в файле build.gradle приводит к ошибке загрузки версии 26.0.2